# TicTacToe with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, string-comparison

At the moment I've got some problems with programming a TicTacToe game with Java Swing.
-the frame shall consist of 9 blank JLabels
-with a click X or an O appears
-the first click on a blank label shall show a X or O but more clicks on the same label have no more influence
-when the last click was an X, the next one should be an O
-it doesn't matter if you start with a X or an O

I wrote those two Classes:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame{
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    SignLabel labels[]= new SignLabel[9];
    public TicTacToe() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            labels[i] = new SignLabel();
            p.add(labels[i]);
        }
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                TicTacToe t = new TicTacToe();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### SignLabel

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SignLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    int value = 0;

    public SignLabel() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        value++;
        value%=2;
        switch(value) {
        case 0:
            if(this.getText() == null) {
                this.setText("X");
            } else if(this.getText() == "O") {
                break;
            } else if(this.getText() == "X") {
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            if(this.getText() == null) {
                this.setText("O");
            } else if(this.getText() == "O") {
                break;
            } else if(this.getText() == "X") {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

If i want to compile the code and start the java file, the wanted window will appear but either there are no labels or the mouse event doesn't work.
I guess the whole stuff with the getText() etc is wrong and the method above doesn't really do what I thought, too.
I would be glad about some help!
Thank you!

Comment: That's not how you need to compare `String`s. You should use `getText().equals("O")` instead of `==`. Also, `getText()` returns an empty string (`""`), not `null`, when there's nothing in the label.

Comment: Also mind that your labels don't have a width, since they are empty. Could be hard to click them.

Comment: There's some value to be had by changing `public class SignLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener` to `public class SignLabel extends JButton implements ActionListener` ..actually, now I think about it, they should likely just be standard buttons, with the game detail stored in a `TicTacToeModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code corrected.

**SignLabel.java**

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SignLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    static boolean value = false;

    public SignLabel() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        value = !value;
        if(getText().length() == 0){
          if(value){
            setText("X");
          }else{
            setText("O");
          }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**TicTacToe.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame{
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    SignLabel labels[]= new SignLabel[9];
    public TicTacToe() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            labels[i] = new SignLabel();
            labels[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            p.add(labels[i]);
        }
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                TicTacToe t = new TicTacToe();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ok, a few things here:

- your label are actually drawn, but without anything written to it you can't see them. At line 17 of ticTacToe.java you can see how I added borders to make sure the labels were there. They are.
- Labels always have a String as a text. Empty, but they have. And empty String is a valid object, so the null comparision will be false. To see if the text is empty you can just check the length of the string getText() returns.
- the whole check to see if there is X or O in the label is useless. Once you know there is something, you can just ignore the click.
- I turned value to a boolean, so you can just switch between the two signs with a not. Also, to make it work, it must be static, otherwise every SignLabel you create will have its own value and you will always mark with an X (I forgot it and i've seen it myself, you remove the static and you can see it too.)

Comment: Also, for your knowledge, for a lot of **Listener Swing provide an equivalent  **Adapter which you can extend, usually with an anonymous class. This way, you can just implement what you need, the other methods will be already implemented as blank methods.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I still have a very complicated way of thinking when I do programming, so I always make the problems heavier as they really are. I didn't know that I could use borders for the edges. That is indeed more comfortable while playing the game. I also just read a few descriptions about the Adapter, changed the code and really have some lines less now! Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem! ;) Accept the answer if it solved the question, thank you.